# How to get project's referenced packages?

Tags: nuget

folks!

Is there any command to know which packages referenced particular project in Nuget?

I cannot find appropriate command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
Get-Package -ProjectName <projectName>
```

to get the list of packages installed for a project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the packages have a list of which projects reference them.

You'd probably have to look at the packages.config files in the individual projects and look for the one you want.

Comment: But pretend that you have a solution, where about 10 different projects. Each project referenced to their packages. So how do I know which packages referenced particular project? That's my problem